# "I can't install the SDK file for the DigitalPersona 4500 fingerprint reader on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, digital-persona-sdk

I've been trying to install the SDK file for the Digital Persona 4500 fingerprint reader for days, however, despite all my efforts, I keep encountering the following error:

Error 1310. Error writing to file:
c:\Windows\system32\pt-BR\DPFpUI.dll.mui. Verify that you have access to that directory.

To solve it, I did all of the following:

Granting all permissions to your user account (SID): Using the icacls command in Command Prompt (CMD) with administrator privileges, granting all permissions to my user account (SID) for the directory in question.

Disabling User Account Control (UAC):

Installing in a different directory

Repairing system permissions: Through the "sfc /scannow" command in a console executed as administrator.

I'm starting to think that it's more of a compatibility issue with Windows 11. Could someone please guide me if there is a way to correctly install the SDK file?

Thanks and greetings to everyone!